# etoolbox conditional causes unwanted empty row in tabular

Tags: tables, etoolbox, conditionals

This code leaves an empty row at the bottom:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\def\somedef{foo}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{|l|}
  \hline
  First row, not important \\ \hline
  \ifdefstring{\somedef}{bar}{never used \\ \hline}{}%
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

The resulting table looks like:

```
----------------------------
| First row, not important |
+--------------------------+
|                          |
```

It's that bogus empty row at the bottom that I want to get rid of.

I know I can make this work by replacing the `\ifdefstring` with something like:

```
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\somedef}{bar}=0 never used \\ \hline \else\fi
```

But I'm interested in sticking to etoolbox, which seems to be a fairly comprehensive package with many relatively easy to read macros (for programmers, my audience).  I'm also interested in using the conditional inline within the table, as that seems easiest to read and maintain.  (If there's a better package that is similarly comprehensive that I should be using instead and it doesn't have the above problem, I'm very interested in hearing about that, too.)

How can I use etoolbox's `\ifdefstring` here without adding the extra row?

I suspect etoolbox either (a) has a bug (missing some `%`), or (b) is inserting something like `\relax`.  Is there some way to discard/eat `\ifdefstring`'s seemingly invisible-yet-row-creating output?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not a bug in etoolbox. Your problem is that `\ifdefstring` does not completely expand in TeX's mouth (it can't, given what it needs to do), and expansion in TeX's mouth is necessary for a macro to do what you want it to.

It all boils down to how TeX parses the data for a `\halign`: To parse data for a column, it reads one token *with* macro expansion, then checks that token (in case it is a `\span` or some other token requiring special processing), then it scans tokens *without* macro expansion until the next `&` or `\cr` (`\\` counts as `\cr` in this context), and then processes all the collected tokens as the data for the present column.

As a consequence, a macro that might or might not produce a row in the table needs to expand to nothing at all if it is not to produce a row, and `\ifdefstring` does not do that.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer.  I only know of the "eyes, mouth, stomach, and bowels" of TeX, not how they work, but after reading this a couple of times it makes sense.  (I could probably benefit from something like _The TeXbook_ here.)

Comment: I recently had a problem like this but came to the opposite conclusion.  If `\halign` reads without macro expansion until finding the next `\cr`, then how is it possible to put e.g. `\crcr` in the "end" part of an environment wrapping around `\halign` and still to work right?  From what you say it seems like the `\end{env}` will hide the carriage return.  I figured that `\halign` expands the first token to check for `\omit` and the like, and, if all is normal, continues expanding down the line until it eventually hits `\cr` or `&`, when it is finished with the current entry.

Answer (score 3):

I see that Harald has covered some of this, but I hope this is also informative.

`etoolbox` uses e-TeX, but not any further extensions as far as I know. So `\pdfsctrcmp` is out  here (for `etoolbox`). So if you read the code, there is an `\edef` inside `\ifdefstring` to carry out the comparison. That's non-expandable, and so it forces a new cell. You see the same with

```
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
  \hline
  First row, not important \\ \hline
  \edef\test{}%
\end{tabular}
```

So I'm not sure you can avoid the issue without defining `\ifdefstring` as you have, with `\pdfstrcmp`. (In LaTeX3, we've decided to require `\pdfstrcmp` as it helps out with lots of otherwise unexpandable tests.)

Comment: Thank you also for your answer.  I was particularly interested to know that (1) `\edef` is "non-expandable," which might seem ironic to the uninformed reader (e.g. me) since I believe `\edef`'s purpose is to "fully expand" before making the definition; and (2) that LaTeX3 requires `\pdfstrcmp`.  Is it still called `\pdfstrcmp` in LaTeX3?  ISTR elsewhere in the TeX universe there is simply `\strcmp` (which may be just an alias for `\pdfstrcmp` where available).  Keeping the "pdf" in there seems odd to me.

Comment: @dsedivec — `\strcmp` is the primitive used by XeTeX, and the `\pdf` prefix is standard for all new pdfTeX primitives. In LaTeX3 it's called `\str_if_eq:nnTF` with several variations, which all work indentically in pdfLaTeX, XeLaTeX, and LuaLaTeX.

Comment: As Will knows but doesn't say, `\str_if_eq:nnTF` is a _higher level wrapper_ around `\pdfstrcmp`. The idea here is that the primitives tend to be rather awkward to work with directly, so the official way to do it in LaTeX3 is _via_ something more controlled, in this case `\str_if_eq:nnTF`. As Will says, this also hides the complexity of the primitive having a different name in pdfTeX and XeTeX, and being written as a short piece of Lua in LuaTeX.

Answer (score 2):

For the future reference of others (and probably myself), to explicitly demonstrate the comments left by Joseph Wright and Will Robertson, this works as well and is probably easier to read:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{expl3}

\def\somedef{foo}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxNamesOn
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
  \hline
  First row, not important \\ \hline
  \str_if_eq:nnTF{\somedef}{bar}{never used \\ \hline}{}%
\end{tabular}
\ExplSyntaxNamesOff

\end{document}
```

`\ExplSyntaxNamesOn` makes `_` and `:` "letters" so you can use them in csnames (or at least that's how I think of it).  `\ExplSyntaxNamesOff` does the opposite.  (Note: don't put those right in the `tabular` around the `\str_if_eq:nnTF` or else you'll still get the empty cell.)

All credit for this goes to Joseph and Will.  Thanks!