# Remove empty row inserted by etoolbox

Tags: tables, conditionals, etoolbox

I generate table with some conditional expression using toolbox package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\providetoggle{ch}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|c|}
  \hline
  Name&value\\\hline
\togglefalse{ch}
\iftoggle{ch}{
    Foo0&0\\\hline
}{}
\toggletrue{ch}
\iftoggle{ch}{
    Foo&12342\\\hline
}{}
\togglefalse{ch}
\iftoggle{ch}{
    bar&0\\\hline
}{}
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image: table with empty row]

It forces new empty row at end of table. Is it posible to remove it, or use some macro that doesn't do that?

Ps. I found the same problem on [etoolbox conditional causes unwanted empty row in tabular](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/5198/etoolbox-conditional-causes-unwanted-empty-row-in-tabular) but solution suggest using expl3 that doesn't work for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wish to keep your tests successive, then this will work:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\providetoggle{ch}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|c|}
  \hline
  Name&value
\togglefalse{ch}%
\iftoggle{ch}{%
    \\\hline Foo0&0%
}{}%
\toggletrue{ch}%
\iftoggle{ch}{%
   \\\hline  Foo&12342%
}{}%
\togglefalse{ch}%
\iftoggle{ch}{%
    \\\hline bar&0%
}{}%
\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

On the other hand, if you are able to nest your conditionals then this will work, as long as at least one conditional is assured of being true:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\begin{document}
\providetoggle{ch}
\begin{tabular}{ |l|c|}
  \hline
  Name&value\\\hline
\togglefalse{ch}%
\iftoggle{ch}{%
  Foo0&0\\\hline%
}{%
  \toggletrue{ch}%
  \iftoggle{ch}{%
    Foo&12342\\\hline%
  }{%
    \togglefalse{ch}%
    \iftoggle{ch}{%
      bar&0\\\hline%
    }{%
    }%
  }%
}%
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Also, some `%` at the end of lines will eliminate stray space tokens.

The key in both these approaches is that you have to end the `tabular` on some actual output (in these cases an `\hline`), rather than false-conditional calculations.

Comment: I need independent conditionals. First solution is perfect. Thank you.